# test case fails on taking app to background using espresso pressBackUnconditionally()

Tags: android-espresso

Scenario:
Launch app
Take app to background using back button
Sleep
Launch app again

I want to execute the above steps using espresso but when I call pressBackUnconditionally() to take app to background, espresso test is finished and fails. Is there any way that test continues and I am able to take app to foreground/background using espresso

Code snippet:

```
public void app_foreground_background(int sleeptime, int overalltimeinmins) throws InterruptedException {
long sleeptimeforscenario = sleeptime * 60000;
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long futureTime = now + overalltimeinmins * 60000;

        try {
            Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally();
            while (futureTime > now) {
String command = "adb -s " + DEVICE ID + " shell am start -n activity”

               getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand(
        command);

                Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally();
                Thread.sleep(sleeptimeforscenario);
                now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```